# How to access command history of `tmux` in non-tmux `zsh` session

Tags: zsh, tmux

I had below in my `.zshrc`

```
export HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history"
export SAVEHIST=10000
export HISTSIZE=$SAVEHIST
setopt HIST_IGNORE_DUPS
setopt HIST_SAVE_NO_DUPS
setopt HIST_NO_STORE
setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE
```

Later,  I realized commands I used inside `tmux` session are not available session outside `tmux`. I assume they're not in `$HOME/.zsh_history` file.
So searched internet made these changes:
in my `.tmux.conf`

```
set -g history-limit 10000
set -g history-file ~/.zsh_history
```

& in my `.zshrc` file set additional history option

```
setopt append_history
setopt hist_expire_dups_first
setopt hist_find_no_dups
setopt hist_ignore_all_dups
setopt inc_append_history
```

After restart, all my command history in `~/.zsh_history` are replaced by the ones that I entered today, all the old commands are gone. I had around 3000+ commands.

I've couple of question

- what might've went wrong with steps that made my history gone
- if `tmux` saved command history, without me explicitly setting `history-file` option in `.tmux.conf` file, can I access that file now? Hoping I could some how restore.
- What should I do to save all commands from various tmux session get saved in common file `~/.zsh_history` on exit of the session.
- is there any best practice to manage command history, in scenarios like above, so that history can be restored across.

Thanks for your time. Your help is much appreciated.

--
Sudhir.

Answer (score 1):

The tmux `history-file` setting is for tmux commands (what you enter after <kbd>Ctrl+B</kbd><kbd>:</kbd>), not shell commands. tmux read from `~/.zsh_history`, probably didn't know what to do with the unexpected format, and either deleted it or modified it enough that zsh couldn't understand it. If you're lucky, `~/.zsh_history` could still have all the commands, just modified somehow.

The settings you're now using will write commands to the history file immediately, but only load the history when you start a new session. If you want the history to be available immediately in all sessions, you can remove `setopt inc_append_history` and add `setopt share_history` (they're incompatible).

For the purposes of history, shell sessions in tmux shouldn't act any different from shell sessions in separate terminal windows, as long as the shell tmux is starting is actually zsh.

Comment: Thank you @yut32, for detailed explanation. Now I see why `~/.zsh_history`  doesn't have any of my previous commands, makes sense. 
is there any performance tradeoff using or not using: `setopt inc_append_history`

Comment: Compared to what? `share_history` will be a bit more expensive, since it has to read the history file after every command you run.